# track javascript events

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tracking

is there a way to track how many times a button has been clicked? I would love for the solution to just involve JS, but if I have to use PHP/MYSQL thats okay. I already have google analytics in place, so I don't know if there is an option there.

the src of the button is just '#' which gets picked up by jquery

Edit: wow, completely didn't realize that I asked the wrong way.  What Im trying to do is more of total user clicking, persistently, not JavaScript event handling. I just want to be able to track how many times the button has been pressed and when

Would something like a post Ajax call to a PHP script be doable?

Comment: Depends on where you want to have the information displayed how many times the button was clicked and if you want to have this information persisted. There are too many options to give one correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Register an onClick event for the button. The onClick handler should do something like load an empty image from your server (but not display it). Then you just count up calls to that gif on the server.

This is how things like Google Analytics work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to roll your own event tracking, Mixpanel might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery:

HTML:

```
<button>Button</button>
<p>Button clicked: </p><input type="text"></input>
```

JS:

```
var buttonClickCount = 0;

$("button").click(function(){
    buttonClickCount++;
    $("input").val(buttonClickCount);
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m8QVz/

Comment: Like i said: you have to be more precise. This is a starting point for you.